# Is it possibile to get elements whose child has a specific class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say a div has three child divs. I want to get the elements only if one of its children has specific class. Is it possible to do it with css?

Comment: there is no parent selector in css yet.

Comment: That would make your CSS browse the DOM upward, it's not possible. Consider using Javascript to add a class to the parent when you add the class to any of the three children.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: you can try out with jQuery using method Closet() because in jquery parent selector is not there

Comment: may be you can use `is('.someclass')`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with CSS alone. You will have to do some javascripting like this.. Replace selector classes with your own.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hasChild = $('div.wrapper div.childClass').length >  0;
    if (hasChild) {
      // add specific class;
      $('div.wrapper').addClass('specific');
    }
});
```

Then you will be able to style the specific class;

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent selector in css but you can use jQuery if you want such kind of selector.

Try following code

```
$('div:has(> a.active)').css('background', 'red');
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1rd71wqk/1/)